# Can we optimize our own meta data?

Tags: discussion

Our title tag is currently:

```html
<title>Webmasters Stack Exchange</title>
```

Our description is:

```html
 <meta name="description" content="Q&amp;A for pro webmasters"/>
```

We have some of the most skilled and knowledgeable SEOs/Webmasters I've encountered. I feel like our site's on-page factors should represent that talent.

I'd be happy to help write up a few ideas.

Comment: Very few people find our site by searching for its home page. Most of our search engine traffic comes from people searching for specific problems for which we have answers.   Optimizing the title and meta description on the home page would have very little SEO impact.

Comment: ... and Google's "generated" description for the homepage (and all other pages for that matter) is already pretty good IMO and adapts to the active questions. I believe this is intentional. Somewhat related... https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7574/when-is-meta-description-still-relevant

Comment: Are there other "meta data" / pages that you would want to target?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm really digging the enthusiasm, and this *would* be a nice-to-have, but it would require us to put in a special request with one of the Stack Exchange Inc. engineers to change it. In light of that, I'm wondering how much it would really affect our KPIs.

I would bet that the grand total of people who discover Webmasters SE through the home page popping up in an organic search result is pretty close to zero. Most of our incoming search traffic is understandably pointed at specific Q&A pages.

So while it would be nice to optimize these tags, my opinion is that it's probably not important enough to bug staff about.

Comment: Copy that. Yeah, agreed in that case it would be a heavy lift. I was sort of also curious in general about our ability to edit things of this nature. Thanks for your answer!